# How do I submit MuiPhoneNumber from material-ui-phone-number in Formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

New to REACT so bear with me please:

I keep getting the initial value of phoneNumber return nothing anytime I submit the form using [material-ui-phone-number](https://github.com/alexplumb/material-ui-phone-number) plugin with [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik). Here is a sample of my code.

```
const initialValues = {
     phoneNumber: "",
  };

const BasicExample = () => (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}>
      {() => (
        <Form>
          <Field
                variant="outlined"
                label="Phone Number"
                name="phoneNumber"
                type="tel"
                fullWidth
                size="small"
                defaultCountry={"gh"}
                as={MuiPhoneNumber}
              />
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to go:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import MuiPhoneNumber from "material-ui-phone-number";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          phoneNumber: ""
        }}
        onSubmit={values => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
        }}
      >
        {formikProps => (
          <Form>
            <MuiPhoneNumber
              defaultCountry={"us"}
              onChange={e => formikProps.setFieldValue("phoneNumber", e)}
            />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Use the `onChange` method of the `MuiPhoneNumber` component to set the new value of the Formik field. There are also other ways but this is the most straight forward I think.